# How to syntax-highlight HTML inside JavaScript strings in VS code?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, web-component

Is there any Vs Code extension to syntax-highlight HTML inside JavaScript strings?

Specifically I am writing web components

```js
const html = content => `
  <div>
    <table>
      ${content}
    </table>
  </div>
`;

class BaseTable extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  set content(value) {
    const template = document.createElement('template');
    template.innerHTML = style + html(value);

    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }
}
```

I want string inside html constant variable to be highlighted

Comment: Just FWIW, that isn't a string, it's a template literal. (Untagged template literals *result* in strings, though. Tagged ones may not.) But I'd expect anything up-to-date that syntax highlights HTML in strings would also handle template literals.

Comment: For future readers: you can use the plugin es6-string-html to highlight HTML template strings prefixed by a comment: `/* html */\`<h1>Hello world</h1>\``. There are es6-string-* plugins for other languages too, like CSS and Markdown.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**If you use lit-html**, There's a plugin in vs code called lit-plugin for syntax highlighting.
Syntax is,

```
const markup = content => html`
  <div>
    <table>
      ${content}
    </table>
  </div>
`;
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Its actually solution to my problem but there is error that html is not defined

Comment: did you import html from lit-html ?

Comment: With this lit-html plugin installed; you don't need to load ``lit-html`` WHEN you define your own ``html`` Tagged template: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: The plugin will also syntax highlight literals that use the built in `String.raw` e.g.
```const markup = String.raw`<div><p>Hi</p></div>`;```

Comment: If you aren't using Lit library, the solution to work with the "lit-html" extension is what @lamplightdev said, use *String.raw*.