# How to get syntax highlighting for Vue templates (where HTML is in JS string literals) in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, vue.js, syntax-highlighting

I'm developing a web app in **Vue 3**, with components described in Javascript files, containing HTML templates in Javascript string literals, for example:

```
app.component('my-alert', {
    props: {
        status: String,
        content: String,
    },
    template:
        `<div class="alert" :class="'alert-'+status" role="alert">
          {{content}}
        </div>`
})
```

My IDE is **Visual Studio 2019**.  I'm aware of plugins for **Visual Studio Code** which enable that IDE to highlight HTML syntax in JS string literals like the above.  (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60207361/3938965) and [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40985912/3938965) for example.)  What I want to know is, are there any similar plugins for ***Visual Studio 2019***?  If there are more than one, are any of them especially designed for Vue.js development?

Comment: Why do you use Visual Studio for Vue development?

Comment: @tauzN The back-end of our app is ASP.NET MVC and our team is used to Visual Studio.  VS Code is a separate product and we don't want to run two different IDEs.

Comment: Fair enough. Unfortunately, I don't think you will find anything as good, or even close to VS Code. You might be able to just open the respective files in VS Code, and compile/build in VS as usual.

Comment: This might not be the answer you want, but if you really want this when most people use VSCode... it is not hard to create a Visual Studio extension. You need to create a `Grammar` folder with a JSON file (can reuse the ones from [here](https://github.com/faisalhakim47/vscode-vue-inline-template/tree/master/syntaxes)) and a `tmTheme` file, plus some other files. I have done this for another language. If there is more interest I can provide a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try es6-string-html extension for Visual Studio Code

Comment `/*html*/` before your string

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31073636)